# S3DistCP copies some files for the manifest and doesnt copy the rest

Tags: amazon-s3, manifest, emr

We are using S3Distcp to copy files from S3 to HDFS by using a manifest file - i.e., we use --copyFromManifest argument in the S3Distcp command. At the S3DistCP step, however, only some of the files are copied that are listed in the manifest. I am not sure where should we start looking for problems - i.e., why are some files being copies and others are not?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe only some nodes copied their portion of the files? Can you check your task node logs to see if any errors occurred?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is you have files with the same name but on different directories. In this case you will need to change the way you construct the **baseName** and **srcDir** fields. Please describe how you build your manifest file.